# Tab bar is not showing its child after rotate the screen to landscape mode in flutter application

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout

I am implementing Tabbar in my application so I have started to learn from dart [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/tabs).

I have tried to run the code provided in the documentation and it is working fine but when I rotate the screen to landscape mode the child of the tab is not displaying.

There are 3 tabs on the screen, go to the 3rd tab and rotate the screen to landscape mode, The tab view of the 3rd tab is not getting display but if I tap on anywhere on the screen then it is getting slide on the screen.

What should the issue that is causing it? Is this an issue with the flutter SDK or I am doing something wrong.

Screenshot for the reference -

[Tabs on portrait mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uZwK.png)

[Tabs after landscape mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2r0P.png)

[Content is getting displayed after taping on the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTMIQ.png)

Comment: what is your code?

Comment: @P4yam, I am running the same code as mentioned in the cookbook of the dart [documentation] (https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/tabs)

Comment: warp your Scafold with Layout Builder

Answer (score 0):

I've also faced this same issue. This happens only at the last time of the index - when changing the mobile from portrait mode to landscape mode. If anyone facing the same issue. Please file a bug in a flutter.

[In LandScape Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yrmid.png)

[In Portrait Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RPVG.png)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching over to the flutter stable channel.

Though it is a bug with dev, that will fix your build. I just ran into this issue.